# Apply selection on Qlik Sense custom extension

Tags: custom-controls, selection, qliksense

I am new to Qlik Sense and I was having some problem when trying to apply selections with a custom Qlik Sense extension. I have tried from [this tutorial](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2018/Subsystems/Extensions/Content/Overview/selection-models.htm). Unfortunately, I have no idea why there is nothing shown, not even error message.

I managed to console log out the things that I selected but Qlik Sense never applies the selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make a selection

```
var app = qlik.currApp();
app.field( "DimensionName" ).selectMatch("Value", false );
```

You can use also selectValues for multiple values :

```
Integers :
app.field(fld).selectValues([5,10], true, true);

Strings :
app.field(fld).selectValues(["Andersson"], true, true);
```

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2018/Subsystems/APIs/Content/CapabilityAPIs/FieldAPI/selectValues-method.htm

Comment: Alright sure thanks so much! Give me a while to try it out!